# Figure in 3 rows

Tags: floats

I need to place two images in this way.

[image]

How can I do?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, titlepage]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc1}
    \caption{img1}
    \label{fig:doc1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc2}
    \caption{img2}
    \label{fig:doc2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc3}
    \caption{img3}
    \label{fig:doc3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My code doesn't do what I want..
Thanks

Comment: You show three subimages in one figure, however, your code contain three figures ... If this images should be in one figure, than just merge them and use `subcaptions` or `subfloat` environments for each image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you load the `subcaption` package and use three `subfigure` environments inside a single `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc1}
    \caption{img1}
    \label{fig:doc1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc2}
    \caption{img2}
    \label{fig:doc2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc3}
    \caption{img3}
    \label{fig:doc3}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To achieve the same look with the machinery of the `subfig` package, you might use something like the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \subfloat[img1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc1}}
   \label{fig:doc1}

    \medskip
    \subfloat[img2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc2}}
    \label{fig:doc2}

    \medskip
    \subfloat[img3]{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{./img/doc3}}    
    \label{fig:doc3}

\caption{bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: faster than me with .5 second.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have this error `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \sf@counterlist

l.108 \begin{document}

?
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \sf@counterlist

l.108 \begin{document}`

Comment: I thihnk the problem is that in my preamble I use also package **subfig**..

Comment: @lonely - Can you stop loading `subfig` and start loading `subcaption`?

Comment: I don't want to replace all the subfloat image with subcaption... Is there a way to do what I want using subfloat?

Comment: @lonely - I've posted an addendum to show how the desired look may be achieved with the machinery of the `subfig` package. A general remark: if you have important information -- such as the fact that you must use the `subfig` package -- it's almost always helpful to reveal it up front.

Comment: @Mico Thanks and sorry, I didn't know that subfig came into conflict with subcaption.